# Create a persistant notification out of a non-persistant one

Tags: notifications, tasker

I'm looking for a way to make my Todoist notifications more "sticky" or persistent.  I've used reminder apps that let you have notifications that keep coming up even after you dismiss them unless you specifically say they are complete.  Or if you don't see or hear the notification, it plays the notification sound again after a user-specified number of minutes, just to make sure you are alerted.  I've been looking for an app that can grab notifications from a specified other app and notify you in this sort of customized way, or a way to do this in Tasker maybe?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a way to make this happen by turning on notification reminders in accessibility settings!